# Is there a court that does not enjoy a full separation of powers aside the ICJ?

Tags: law, international

> The International Court does not enjoy a full separation of powers,
> with permanent members of the Security Council being able to veto
> enforcement of cases, even those to which they consented to be
> bound.[73] Because the jurisdiction does not have binding force
> itself, in many cases, the instances of aggression are adjudicated by
> Security Council by adopting a resolution, etc. There is, therefore, a
> likelihood for the permanent member states of Security Council to
> avoid the legal responsibility brought up by International Court of
> Justice, as shown in the example of Nicaragua v. United States.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Court_of_Justice

> Separation of powers refers to the division of a state's government
> into branches, each with separate, independent powers and
> responsibilities, so that the powers of one branch are not in conflict
> with others. The typical division into three branches of government,
> sometimes called the trias politica model, includes a legislature, an
> executive, and a judiciary. It can be contrasted with the fusion of
> powers in monarchies, but also parliamentary and semi-presidential
> systems where there can be overlap in membership and functions between
> different branches, especially the executive and legislative.

Is there a court that does not enjoy a full separation of powers aside the ICJ? I am mostly asking for international court, but if there isn't any other international court that feature such a idiosyncrasy, if there's a court inside a country with the same flaw. I am guessing North Korea and China, but outside of them is there any other court like that?

Comment: You might run into a definitional problem with this question. In some government systems, if something does not have full independence, it is not a court *by definition* (it would be something more like a tribunal). Or maybe you asking that broadly: whether there are bodies that adjudicate disputes that are not fully independent?

Comment: What does full independence mean? Getting on SCOTUS requires consent of the president and senate, and if SCOTUS makes a ruling that Congress doesn't like, they can impeach everyone who voted for it.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, no international body has general enforcement powers over anything. International bodies have exactly as much power as their constituent sovereigns are willing to give them, and not an inch more.

Comment: I've voted to close, as the terms here are too fuzzy, to the point that no court has "full separation of powers".  Certainly no international court, and (nearly) all national courts have appointment and dismissal procedures, and clemency procedures that lie with the legislature or executive.

Comment: "International courts" in particular have no powers to separate. They essentially issue recommendations, upon which any nation may act or ignore. If the nation acts upon it, it gets a solid justification for its actions, but that's it. You're free to establish your own international court, as long as you get enough nations to give it tokens of respect.

Comment: Read the Wikipedia article on [Judicial independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judicial_independence) which discusses some countries with imperfect separation of powers; there are also country-specific articles such as on the problematic situation in [Russia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judiciary_of_Russia) and [Poland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judiciary_of_Poland). It's common to have judges at least partly chosen by politicians and their salaries set by legislatures and for politicians to intervene in trials to different extents (even public comments can threaten independence).